# Why Scanning twice one after another and storing in a char variables ruins the first one?

Tags: c, char, scanf

I do have a problem regarding using scanf specially when i want to store the variable in a char variable....

Here's the code that I am using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char min,max;
printf("Please enter two number to create an array with numbers in between: ");
scanf("%d",&min);
printf("%d\n",min);
scanf(" %d",&max);
printf("%d %d\n",max,min);
}
```

I tried using fflush(stdin) after the first scanf and I also tried leaving a space just before " %d " in the second scanf or after the first one and nothing works>>>> So what happens is whenever the second scanf works, whatever got stored in the first one is replaced by zero>>>

Try to neglect the 5 numbers below, it's within a code i didn't enter here.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d19te.png)

Comment: Either `%d` is the wrong format specifier, it should be `%c`, or `char` is the wrong type, it should be `int`. The mismatch causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Why squeeze an integer (or two) into a single byte (or two)? AND, `scanf()` returns a value that this code is not using...

Comment: IOW: most certainly `char` -> `int`

Comment: Didn't your compiler mention something about an argument type mismatch? Always listen to your compiler.

Comment: Ahmed El-Shaer, when reading in a number, what is the maximum acceptable value?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica let's say the max entry is a char as written in code which is 255 in numbers.

Comment: @Gerhardh Haven't seen anything being showed by the compiler :)

Comment: @Jabberwocky  That's the easy work around which the one that i am not looking for but thanks alot!

Comment: @fe203 i don't wanna use the return of the scanf, but regarding the part of squeezing, i don't really get what you mean, can you elaborate please?

Comment: If you are expecting values up to 255, then a `char` is not suitable as it can be signed. Use `unsigned char` instead.

Comment: Why don't you want to use return value of `scanf`? Don't you care if your program runs properly? How else would you expect to notice if a user did not enter a proper number?

Answer (score 3):

> … i want to store the variable in a char …

If you really want to store the value in a `char` variable, you need the *length modifier* `hh`, i. e. `scanf("%hhd", &min)` and `scanf("%hhd", &max)`.

Comment: The C standard says: _`hh` Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, `X`, or `n` conversion specifier applies
to an argument with type pointer to `signed char` or `unsigned char`._

Comment: I've tried doing the hh as you mentioned but still it don't work, seems like always the second entry in the second scanf is taking the place of the first in the memory for some reason. probably because of %d is for integers only.

Comment: Based on what observation do you say it _seems like always the second entry in the second scanf is taking the place of the first_?

Comment: Besides, it can't be _because of %d is for integers only_, since the type `char` is an integer type.

Answer (score 0):

**Save time, enable all compiler warnings**

OP's code has *undefined behavior* (UB) as `"%d"` matches a `int *`, not a `char *`.

```
char min,max;
scanf("%d",&min);  // Bad
```

---

To save numeric decimal text as an *integer* in a character integer type, use

```
signed char min;    
scanf("%hhd", &min);
```

or

```
unsigned char min;    
scanf("%hhu", &min);
```

As OP has "max entry is a char as written in code which is 255 in numbers", use

```
unsigned char min;    
scanf("%hhu", &min);
```

---

In all cases, good code checks the `scanf()` return value to know valid text was converted.

```
unsigned char min;    
if (scanf("%hhu", &min) == 1) {
  puts("Success");
} else {
  puts("Failed. Text remains in stdin");
}
```